# Как внедрить версию библиотеки из другой ветки в maven?

Tags: java, git, maven, library

Есть большой проект, в него подтягиваются библиотеки с gitlab к которым у меня есть доступ. Мне нужно поменять некоторые методы в этих библиотеках и продебажить. Коллега сказал, что можно просто создать свою ветку, в pom файлах указать новую версию, и подтянуть эту версию к себе в репозиторий (и играться с библиотекой как душа хочет). Может сталкивался кто с подобной задачей? Пробовал вместо версии указывать название векти, в итоге подтянул пару каких-то непонятных файла.

Answer (score 0):

Мавен тут непричем это работа с git.
Если вы используете intellij idea то можете воспользоваться встроенными функциями вместо обычных консольных команд. Зачастую это проще..

Приложил скрин нижнего правого угла idea для большей разборчивости. Нажимаете на Git и увидите имеющиеся ветки и возможности по их управлению. В этом же всплывающем меню вы можете по ним перемещаться.

Но помните что ветка создается на основе настоящей ветки на которой вы находитесь (скорее всего вы находитесь на master - это основная ветка проекта по дефолту).

В том же углу на нижней панели можно увидеть на какой ветке вы находитесь (поле Git:myBranch2)

Local Branches - те ветки которые существуют только в вашей локальной сети (на вашем компьютере).
Remote Branches - ветки которые запушены в GitLab или другой Git..

При создании, изначально ветка отобразится в Local Branches и вы автоматически на нее перейдете.

Вы так же в идее можете увидеть схему веток (откуда что отделается и с чем сливается) на той же панели в левой ее части, во вкладке Version Control -> log. Там же отображены все коммиты и на каком из них какая ветка находится.

Советую ознакомиться с гайдом по веткам если вы работаете над enterprise-проектом. Intellij idea позволяет так же коммитить, пушить, пулить и др без использования консоли, просто загуглите об этом или спросите меня)

[image: idea]